# Using two bibliographies with and without backref

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, back-referencing

For my thesis, I would like to generate a smaller bibliography in the beginning that includes only my previous work that was adapted in the thesis, in addition to a (normal) bibliography. Some entries might appear in both bibliographies. This works rather well when using biblatex:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backref=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha Title},
  keywords = {self}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, keyword=self, title={Previously Published Work}]

\chapter{First}
Some text \cite{A01}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={References}]

\end{document}
```

However, I would like to get rid of the backrefs in the first listing and re-enabling them for the second. Is this possible with biblatex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by scoping one of the `\printbibliopgraphy` commands  within a group and redefining the `pageref` bib macro to be empty in that group. Namelly:

```
\begingroup
\renewbibmacro{pageref}{}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, keyword=self, title={Previously Published Work}]
\endgroup
```

This produces

[image]

for the first `\printbibliography` (the one enclosed by  the group) and

[image]

for the second `\printbibliography`.