# Hyperref to specific \printbibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, biber

In my dissertation I have to list the papers it is based on at the beginning of the document.
So I have the statement

```
\printbibliography[keyword=own,heading=none]
```

at one of the first pages, where the keyword 'own' selects my papers.
Then, around the end I print the full bibliography (including my own papers as well):

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

However, now every time I `\cite` to one of my own papers the link that is created links to the first bibliography. So if I click the citation in the main text I jump to the front.
I use biblatex, biber, and hyperref.
Is there anyway to print the (partial) bibliography without registering the keys for linking?

Edit: an example

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,safeinputenc]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{local.bib}
    @unpublished{myown,
        Author = {Joran},
        Title = {My own paper},
        keywords = {own}
    }
    @unpublished{notmyown,
        Author = {Someone},
        Title = {This is not my own paper},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{local.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,heading=none]
\clearpage
\noindent An example of my own paper: \cite{myown}\\
An example of another paper: \cite{notmyown}
\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142632/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303503/35864. Near-duplicates: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140048/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/448694/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is an official interface (yet). But you can suppress locally the creation of the anchors, then biblatex will create them in the main bibliography:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,safeinputenc]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{local.bib}
    @unpublished{myown,
        Author = {Joran},
        Title = {My own paper},
        keywords = {own}
    }
    @unpublished{notmyown,
        Author = {Someone},
        Title = {This is not my own paper},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{local.bib}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makeatletter\def\blx@anchor{}
\printbibliography[keyword=own,heading=none]
\endgroup
\clearpage
\noindent An example of my own paper: \cite{myown}\\
An example of another paper: \cite{notmyown}
\clearpage
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```